# Not able to change value of Database Cell Based on Select Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this situation:

Table A

```
|id|cgid|description|
---------------------
|00|0002|some text 1|
|01|0001|some text 2|
|02|0002|some text 3|
|03|0003|some text 4|
|04|0005|some text 5|
```

and Table B

```
|a_id|cpid|
-----------
|  00| 010|
|  00| 312|
|  00| 040|
|  01| 020|
|  01| 312|
|  01| 030|
|  02| 210|
|  02| 312|
|  02| 130|
```

`a_id` is the join column for `id` of Table A.

Now I need to change all the rows in table B with `cpid=312` to `250` but only when the cgid of Table `A is 0002`.

I can select all those entries with the following command:

```
SELECT  *
FROM        A
JOIN        B
ON          A.id = B.a_id
WHERE       A.cgid LIKE '0002'
AND         B.cpid = 312
```

Any Help or Ideas would be very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Update with INNER JOIN. Refer [Here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html)

```
UPDATE B
SET B.cpid = 250
FROM A 
WHERE A.id = B.a_id AND A.cgid LIKE '0002' 
     AND B.cpid = 312
```